# window.navigator.userAgent is appearing blank in QTWebbrowser

Tags: browser, qtwebkit, navigator

I need to add browser specific check for my UI to behave properly in different browsers.  **window.navigator.userAgent** is giving info for most of the standard web browsers but for QTWebbrowser it is coming blank. Is there any alternative to indentify a browser??.[image]